# Django REST | Globally exclude some fields in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to globally exclude or include some fields from all models?

I have fields like "active", "created_time", "updated_time", "created_by", "updated_by"  on all models, these are making extra load on the response unless specified in exclude.

Is there a way to exclude them globally, unless it's specified in fields?

Comment: Just a recommendation: Specify the fields you want included in `Meta.fields` on your serializer, it avoids these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest solution, but this is how I do it with inheritance and specific reference to the parent serializer's `Meta` class:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    notes = MarkdownNoteSerializer(many=True,required=False,allow_add_remove=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('url', 'creation_datetime', 'update_datetime','notes')

class RipeSampleSerializer(SampleSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RipeSample
        fields = SampleSerializer.Meta.fields + ( 'ripe', )
```

You can then include or exclude the fields by explicitly referring or not referring to the fields.

There's also no reason why you can't create sets of tuples to include in the fields:

```
SampleFields = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
OtherFields = ('update', 'creation')

[...]
fields = SampleFields + OtherFields + ('yahoo',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create mixin that will override `get_fields` method:

```
class CustomFieldsMixin(object):
    def _get_exlude_fields(self):
        return ["active", "created_time", "updated_time", "created_by", "updated_by"]

    def _get_include_fields(self):
        return {"name": serializers.CharField()}

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(CustomFieldsMixin, self).get_fields()

        for exclude_field in self._get_exclude_fields():
            if exclude_field in fields:
                del field[fields]

        for include_field, include_field_value in self._get_include_fields().items():
            if include_field not in fields:
                 field[include_field] = include_field_value

        return fields
```

(This is code is just example of basic idea)

And use mixin if each serializer:

```
class SampleSerializer(CustomFieldsMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer)
```